# Using LINQ to find a specific value in a List

Tags: c#, list, linq, keyvaluepair

I'm trying to use LINQ to find a specific string value "ConstantA" in a List.

Variable "stuff" is a type of:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
```

The first value in the List (StuffName) is the one that I'm looking for:

[image]

How do I use LINQ to find the correct StuffName = "ConstantA"?

This is my code below:

```
var listOfStuff = CalculateStuff();
foreach (var stuff in listOfStuff)
{
  if (stuff.Constants.FindAll("ConstantA") //**I’m having problem with LINQ here**
  {
   …
  }
}


private static List<Stuff> CalculateStuff()
{
…
}

public class Stuff : IHasIntInst
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Constants { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get all instances in Constants that match 'ConstantA'? If so, why have you got it in an 'if'? Are you only trying to do something if there is at least one instance of ConstantA?

Comment: Correct sr28, if there's found one instance of 'ConstantA', then do specific something.

Comment: i think this question is super easy to solve but super hard to understand what you want.

Comment: stuff.Constants.Where(c => c.Key == "ConstantA") to get all the constants which have the key called "ConstantA". or something like that. But maybe not because the question can be easily interpreted in different ways.. "StuffName" does not exist in your code for example. It is probably the key? then dont call it "StuffName". And so on

Answer (score 1):

**With your current version of code:**

```cs
var listOfStuff = CalculateStuff();
foreach (var stuff in listOfStuff)
{
    var items = stuff.Constants.FindAll((keyValuePair) => keyValuePair.Key == "ConstantA");
    if (items.Any())
    {
        //**I’m having problem with LINQ here**
    }
}
```

---

In case if you don't want items but only want to check condition, use **LINQ** `Any` method:

```cs
foreach (var stuff in listOfStuff)
{
    if (stuff.Constants.Any((keyValuePair) => keyValuePair.Key == "ConstantA"))
    {
        {
            //**I’m having problem with LINQ here**
        }
    }
}
```

---

In case if your `Stuff` class is defined using `Dictionary`:

```cs
public class Stuff
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Constants { get; set; }
}
```

**and usage:**

```cs
var listOfStuff = CalculateStuff();
foreach (var stuff in listOfStuff)
{
    var items = stuff.Constants.Where((kvp) => kvp.Key == "ConstantA");

    if (items.Any())
    {
        //**I’m having problem with LINQ here**
    }
}
```

> Note that with both cases usage is same, which means changing 
>   `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` to `Dictionary<string, string>` will not affect much code.

---

And finally a version I prefer the most )
The `Stuff` class would be:

```cs
public class Stuff
{
    public string StuffName { get; set; }
    public int StuffValue { get; set; }
}
```

Next, the calculate method would be:

```cs
private static List<Stuff> CalculateStuff()
{
    return new List<Stuff>()
    {
        new Stuff{StuffName = "ConstantA", StuffValue = 100},
        new Stuff{StuffName = "ConstantB",StuffValue = 200}

    };
}
```

**And the usage:**

```cs
var listOfStuff = CalculateStuff().Where(st => 
                                         st.StuffName == "ConstantA");

foreach (var stuff in listOfStuff)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {stuff.StuffName}, Value: {stuff.StuffValue}");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot because in this case it would be changing someone else's code :( but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @ichachan, sure I understand, but you can try to suggest change, anyway ;)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but for KeyValuePair I got an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>>' to 'bool' "

Comment: @ichachan the error is because you put the collection in the if statement, which you can't do, because `if` statement is accepting only boolean expression, that is why I've put items.Any() because it's returning boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to just check for at least one instance of ConstantA then just use 'Any()' like this:

```
if (stuff.Constants.Any(x => x.Key == "ConstantA")
{
    //do something....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I think this might work! Doing some testing now.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the problem raised, I propose two different approaches both of them using **Linq** hoping that you will be useful .

***1 - First Approache :***

```
var result = listOfStuff.SelectMany(e => e.Constants.Select(d => d))
                        .Where(e=> e.Key == "ConstantA");
```

***2 - Second Approache :***

```
 var result = from item in listOfStuff.SelectMany(e => e.Constants)
             where item.Key =="ConstantA"
             select item ;
```